# Change the system settings on the change of settings in the application

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have an UWP application which display the battery status. On change of power saving mode in the application need to reflect in System settings.

Is it possible in UWP?

Comment: You can open the setting and make the user to set the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible in UWP?

No, this is not possible in UWP. We can't change System Settings just within a UWP app programmatically. As @lindexi said, the proper way to achieve what you want is launching the **Settings** app and then let user change the battery saver setting.

To launch to the battery saver setting page, we can use **"ms-settings:batterysaver"** URI like the following:

```
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:batterysaver"));
```

For more info, please see [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

And after this, we can use [PowerManager.EnergySaverStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Power.PowerManager#Windows_System_Power_PowerManager_EnergySaverStatus) property to check if user has enabled battery saver.